# system of 4 first order differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My calculus is a little rusty, can anyone show me how to solve:

$x'(t)=1, y'(t)=0, z'(t)=w, w'(t)=-z$

I can solve the first two components without any issues, but stuck on the last two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: you can reduce last pair of equations to $z'' + z = 0$. This is a linear homogeneous constant-coefficient ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $z'=w\implies z''=w'$, hence setting $w'(t)=z$, one should get $$z''+z=0$$

solving for complementary function, $$(D^2+1)z=0\implies D=\pm i$$

writing the general solution, 
$$z=e^0(A\sin t+B\cos t)=A\sin t+B\cos t$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{cases}
x'(t)=1\\
y'(t)=0\\
z'(t)=w\\
w'(t)=-z
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\int x'(t)\space\text{d}t=\int1\space\text{d}t\\
\int y'(t)\space\text{d}t=\int0\space\text{d}t\\
z'(t)=w\\
w'(t)=-z
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=t+\text{C}_1\\
y(t)=\text{C}_2\\
w(t)=z'(t)\\
w'(t)+z(t)=0
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=t+\text{C}_1\\
y(t)=\text{C}_2\\
w'(t)=z''(t)\\
w'(t)+z(t)=0
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=t+\text{C}_1\\
y(t)=\text{C}_2\\
w'(t)=z''(t)\\
z''(t)=-z(t)
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=t+\text{C}_1\\
y(t)=\text{C}_2\\
w'(t)=z''(t)\\
\int z''(t)z'(t)\space\text{d}t=-\int z'(t)z(t)\space\text{d}t
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=t+\text{C}_1\\
y(t)=\text{C}_2\\
w'(t)=z''(t)\\
z(t)=\text{C}_3\sin(t)+\text{C}_4\cos(t)
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t)=t+\text{C}_1\\
y(t)=\text{C}_2\\
w(t)=\text{C}_3\cos(t)-\text{C}_4\sin(t)\\
z(t)=\text{C}_3\sin(t)+\text{C}_4\cos(t)
\end{cases}
$$